# How to populate volume bar chart below line chart in green when it increases and red when it decreases from previous value

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

```
import os
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import  pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.max_open_warning': 0})

pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')

pth = "D:/Technical_Data/"
for fle in os.listdir(pth):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pth, fle),usecols=(0,4,5,10))
    if not df.empty:
       df=df.astype(float)
       days = pd.to_datetime(df['indx'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
       value = df['Close']
       open_v = df['MA_50']
       fig = plt.figure()
       plt.plot_date(x=days, y=value,fmt="r-")
       plt.plot_date(x=days, y=open_v,fmt="g-")
       fig.autofmt_xdate()
       plt.xticks(2013,2014,2015,2016)
       plt.ylabel("Price")
       plt.grid(True)
       pp.savefig()
       volume = df['Volume']
       plt.clf()
pp.close()
```

I use this code to populate line chart with two columns on Y-axis and date values on X-axis.
I want to do one more thing is add volume bar below line chart . Color is red when volume decrease from previous value and green when increases.

```
indx    open    High    Low Close   Volume
20141015    0.345   0.365   0.32    0.34    5540100
20141016    0.34    0.34    0.32    0.325   2044700
20141017    0.32    0.35    0.315   0.34    1818000
20141020    0.36    0.39    0.36    0.385   798900
20141021    0.39    0.41    0.39    0.395   2981500
20141022    0.415   0.43    0.39    0.39    2997900
20141023    0.4 0.4 0.37    0.375   458900
20141024    0.375   0.39    0.375   0.385   90000
20141027    0.38    0.38    0.355   0.38    562900
20141028    0.375   0.38    0.36    0.37    684300
20141029    0.375   0.38    0.365   0.37    339300
```

Honestly I tried doing it by by myself . I am finding matplotlib very hard as compared to only python . Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've minimised you code down to just plot the bars; I'll leave it to you to incorporate into the rest of your script.

Here is how to plot the bars from your DataFrame, and then change the bars to red if they have a height less than the previous bar:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
            'indx':[20141015,20141016,20141017,20141020,20141021,20141022,20141023,20141024,20141027,20141028,20141029],
            'Volume':[5540100,2044700,1818000,798900,2981500,2997900,458900,90000,562900,684300,339300]
            }).astype(float)


fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

days = pd.to_datetime(df['indx'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
volume = df['Volume']

# Plot all bars with green facecolor 
bars = ax.bar(np.array(days),volume,facecolor='g')

# Loop over bars
for i, bar in enumerate(bars):
    if i == 0: 
        continue

    # Find bar heights
    h = bar.get_height()
    h0 = bars[i-1].get_height()

    # Change bar color to red if height less than previous bar
    if h < h0: bar.set_facecolor('r')

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Basically you loop over the `Rectangle` patches created by `ax.bar`, and interrogate them to find their heights. Then, use `.set_facecolor()` to change the relevant bars.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Final note: because the scales are so different between the price and the volume, you may want to use a [`twinx`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx) axes to plot the volume bars. See [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html) for more.